# react-native Picker where 2nd picker's item is dependent on the selectedValue of the 1st picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, picker

I have 2 picker 1 main picker where in the 2nd picker's items will depend on it's selected value. Each Subfilter's list is loaded on ComponentDidMount.

*Picker1) FilterBy:* All, Category, Status

*Picker2) SubFilter:* All, if Picker1 === Category show {item1, item2, item3 ...}, if Picker1 === Status show {Open, Cancelled, Rejected, Done}

**Scenario:**

1. Select 'Category' on FilterBy: setFilterBy which is FilterBy's setState will be triggered.
2. SubFilter's List Item for Category will render.
3. Select SubFilter value where in the the selected value does not exist on the other list's values in this case in Status's Subfilter List. setSubFilter setState will be triggered.
4. Will call to fetch a filtered list base on the selected filters.
5. Reselect a new FilterBy: this time 'Status'.
6. App Closes.

**IMPORTANT NOTE**

Upon changing of the FilterBy it also sets the SubFilter's value to 0 which should supposedly address the possible problem of when the current selected SubFilter's value does not exist on the list. It proves to work because when I initially select any value that can also exist on Status List's indexes it does reset the value of SubFilter to 0 but for some reason it the value I selected does not exist in Status's List it doesn't?

Removing the selectedValue on the Picker's props works but this is not the correct way since it will not display the current selected value. But it does filter the displayed List correctly.

Reselecting the default value 'ALL' of the SubFilter before reselecting a new FilterBy value also works fine.

All ready tried separating the rendering of the Pickers. It does not work. Tried converting FilterBy's value to string on selectedValue. Also tried putting conditions on the selectedValue.

```
<Grid style={styles.alignCenter}>
              <Col>
                <Text>Filter by:</Text>
              </Col>
              <Col size={3}>
                <Form>
                  <Picker
                    id="Filter"
                    mode="dropdown"
                    iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                    style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1 }}
                    selectedValue={filterBy}
                    onValueChange={itemValue => {
                      setSelectedCategory(0);
                      setSelectedStatus(0);
                      setCurrentPage(1);
                      setFilterBy(itemValue);
                    }}
                  >
                    <Picker.Item key="0" label="Select Filter" value="key0" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Category" value="key1" />
                    <Picker.Item label="Status" value="key2" />
                  </Picker>
                </Form>
              </Col>
            </Grid>
            <Grid style={styles.alignCenter}>
              <Col style={styles.marginTop10}>
                <Text>SubFilter</Text>
              </Col>
              <Col size={3} style={styles.marginTop10}>
                <Form>
                  {filterBy === 'key1' ? (
                    <Picker
                      mode="dropdown"
                      iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                      style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1 }}
                      selectedValue={selectedCategory}
                      onValueChange={itemValue => {
                        setCurrentPage(1);
                        setSelectedStatus(0);
                        setSelectedCategory(0);
                        refetch();
                      }}
                    >
                      <Picker.Item key="0" label="All" value="0" />
                      {categoryList &&
                        categoryList.getTaskCategoryList.list.map(item => (
                          <Picker.Item
                            label={item.category_name}
                            value={item.id}
                            key={item.id}
                          />
                        ))}
                    </Picker>
                  ) : filterBy === 'key2' ? (
                    <Picker
                      mode="dropdown"
                      iosIcon={<Icon name="arrow-down" />}
                      style={{ width: '100%', flex: 1 }}
                      selectedValue={selectedStatus}
                      onValueChange={itemValue => {
                        setCurrentPage(1);
                        setSelectedCategory(0);
                        setSelectedStatus(0);
                        refetch();
                      }}
                    >
                      <Picker.Item key="0" label="All" value="0" />
                      {Object.values(TaskStatus)
                        .slice(1)
                        .map((item, idx) => (
                          <Picker.Item
                            label={item}
                            value={idx}
                            key={item}
                          />
                        ))}
                    </Picker>
                  ) : null}
                </Form>
              </Col>
            </Grid>
```

Comment: If i understood correctly on changing first filter(picker) it should set some data in 2nd filter(picker).or not?

Comment: Yes, it will be the deciding factor in which list should be rendered for the 2nd picker.

Comment: From looking your code on changing the first filter,you are rendering a second filter.Since you are conditionally rendering the 2nd list, everytime first list changes it will initialise the 2nd list with a initial value like 0th as you have mentioned.What you can do is maintain separate state variable for each of the possible 2nd pickers.This way it will not be reset.

Comment: @ThakurKarthik are you saying I should have separate variable for category and status?

Comment: No it will be like firstFilter:[all|category|status],subfilter1:[activeitemof1stlist|first-itemof1stlist],subfilter2:[activeitemof2ndlist|first-itemof2ndlist],....

Comment: As I understood your app crashes when you reselect the filter by value, What I didn't get is why are you calling values from componentdidmount.I will suggest you to use componentwillreceiveprops.

Comment: @Iva what I meant is on ComponentDidMount a call to the backend will trigger which will get the lists for the items in category and status. Kind of like an onload function that fetches the data that will be rendered in the DOM.